# Visual Studio, Knockout and Razor: unwanted white space added

Tags: visual-studio-2012, knockout.js

I'm looking for a solutions or a workaround to the issue where if I Format Document in Visual Studio (which I do all the time)

This

```
data-bind="value: Url, localDataOrHeadOfficeData: useOfficeUrl, localData: Url, headOfficeData: '@Model.Url'"
```

becomes this (note the spaces after @Model.Url)

```
data-bind="value: Url, localDataOrHeadOfficeData: useOfficeUrl, localData: Url, headOfficeData: '@Model.Url    '"
```

Comment: Reset your settings, because I don't facing this problem.

Comment: I am also seeing a similar behavior, extra spaces inserted after the 'data-bind' tag. I have not found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `@string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "'", Model.Url)` although it's more verbose and takes more effort.